# Is there any way I can make an ordered list look like in my example below

Tags: jquery, html, css

I would like to make an ordered list with HTML that looks like this:

```
2.1 tesa
2.2 tesbasdfasd
2.3 asfdasd
2.4 sdfsd
```

Is it possible to do this? I really want to use **ol** and a **li** because I like the way it gives space for the numbers if there's more than one line.

Answer (score 4):

One way to do it with CSS:

**HTML:**

```
<ol id="myList">
    <li>tesa</li>
    <li>tesbasdfasd</li>
    <li>asfdasd</li>
    <li>sdfsd</li>
<ol>
```

**CSS:**

```
#myList {
    list-style: decimal inside none;
    margin-left: 2em;
}
#myList li:before {
    content: "2.";
    float: left;
}
```

[**See it at jsFiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/PBq39/)

This should work on all late-model browsers.  [Compatibility table](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t15).

Comment: this, however, does not addresses the OP request for: ***a)*** no `.` after the numbers and ***b)*** maintain the spacing of the numbers from the text for multiline `li` cases..

Comment: @Gaby: The OP does not specifically state "no `.` after the numbers (although the sample shows it).  The rest is not clear.  But your answer does render better for "unruly" HTML, +1.

Comment: indeed the `.` is not mentioned.. I interpreted the image as requirements (*might not be the case though*)..

Comment: The answer that Elad gave me looks interesting. Can you comment on this. It seems too good to be true. Will it work in all the recent browsers?

Comment: Yes, the link that Elad pointed to should work on all recent, major browsers.  You may need a `DOCTYPE` to get it to work on IE 8.

Answer (score 2):

I think this might do the trick for you:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS_Counters

Answer (score 1):

This is the best i can come up with (*all modern and IE8+ browser support*)

```
ol{
    counter-reset:list;
    list-style-type:none;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
ol li{
    counter-increment:list;
    position:relative;
    padding-left:3em;
}

ol li:before{
    width:2em;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    text-align:right;
}
/*add one of the following classes to the <ol> to define the prefix*/
ol.prefix-1 li:before{
    content: '1.' counter(list);
}
ol.prefix-2 li:before{
    content: '2.' counter(list);
}
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/rmCJC/1

It will render as

[image]

Comment: That's pretty good. Of course sometime I will want to start with a 1 then a 2 then a 3. I guess I could do that with an inline style?

Comment: @Rene, you can use a class to define the prefix like [this updated example](http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/rmCJC/1/) (***updated answer as well to reflect the changes***)

Comment: Already gave it a +1.  This answer would get my vote.  Mine's simpler, but this renders much better.  I'd "fix" my answer but you beat me to it.